# Accessing local Git branch between developer machines

Tags: git

Here is a scenario:
There are 2 developers working on a Git repo (say GitHub).
Is it possible for Developer1 to push changes to Developer2 machine without involving remote repository (GitHub).

Note that both Dev machines simply have Git installed on their machines.

While I understand it's possible to add remote repo to a local repo, I am not sure how to expose a local branch as a server, something like:

https://Dev1Machine/DevLocalBranch.git

Comment: I'm not sure I see the value of doing that.  Pushing it to a common remote reduces the headache of trying to configure any other remotes between yourselves, eliminates the possibility of the push failing due to IPs changing, and is generally safer.  Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: @Makoto this is a scenario when 2 devs are working on something and quickly want to check other's branch. The problem with using a remote branch is 2 fold 1> It again goes against the concept of truly distributed version control, we are still in server-client mode. 2> Having too many dead branches on remote repository causes bloated repository. With 300 people working on repository, I can say for certain that this is a problem. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

If one developer (let's say Developer2) exposes his Git repository with an HTTP server or over SSH, then this is possible. You could also expose the folder with the repository as a file share (SMB or Windows share, depending on your OS) and then access it via a `file://` url, for example:

```
file:///networkshare/repositories/yourrepo.git
```

However, it's only possible to expose the whole repository, not a single branch. For Developer1 it's then just another remote repository, just with a url in your local network.

But in my opinion, the effort to setup this correctly so that it works, is much higher as to just pushing to your Github repo and dealing with old personal branches later (removing them, if not needed any more etc.). To keep your personal branches separated from others, you can use a prefix for those branches, like `personal/` or similar.